# php - Difference $_SESSION behavior in php 5.2 and 5.5

Tags: php, class, session

I have the following code example that works as I expected on PHP 5.5, but in the hosting server I have PHP 5.2.17 and it does not.

If I re run it several times, I get what I was expecting, the array gets bigger with different numbers.

But when I run it on PHP 5.2.17 I get the same number, as the instance of `class A` is frozen.

Evenmore, If I remove this line `$_SESSION['a'] = $a;` then it works on PHP 5.2.17, but it is not what I need. Anyone with knowledge of PHP releases could think of a way to manage this. Thanks

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $var = 0;
}

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['a_array']))
{

    $a = new A();
    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
    $a->var = rand();

    array_push($_SESSION['a_array'], $a);

}
else
{

    $a_array = Array();
    $_SESSION['a_array'] = $a_array;

}

var_dump($_SESSION['a_array']);

?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put the entire object into a session variable? That's at least what it looks like.

Comment: I think I do, I need to acces the object $a, from another script. So i need this $_SESSION['a'] = $a;

Comment: You shouldn't do it that way. Make another php and put just the class into the file. Once you do that include the file/class in the page that you need to access it then you can still do: $a = new A() to get access to that class as long as the other page is included

Comment: In the practice I do that, this is just a self consistent example, so you could cut and paste it and it works.

Comment: Does php 5.2 generate different numbers actually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/603478/why-cant-i-store-a-php-class-instance-as-a-session-variable

Comment: Only if I comment this line $_SESSION['a'] = $a;. For example this is an output: array(2) { [0]=> &object(A)#2 (1) { ["var"]=> int(856358305) } [1]=> object(A)#2 (1) { ["var"]=> int(856358305) } }

Comment: Thanks for the link @NicholasYoung, I changed the order and is the same.

Comment: This just highlights the need to have a consistent development & production environment. You should consider running a VM or something similar that uses the same versions of the software you use in production to develop on. It'd save you a lot of time. PHP 5.5 has a LOT of new features compared to 5.2, and a lot of changes.

Comment: You are completely right. In this case I think I will change the hosting, it has just old releases of everithing.

Comment: Probably the best course of action to be honest. Good luck!

Comment: Can you explain what it is exactly that you're trying to do?  I'm having trouble following the code example.  It might be a bit **too** minimal without context.

Comment: Ok. I am trying to fill an array with classes instances that I could change from other scripts, that way I need to storage the last instance on SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a dirty and bizzarre solution. I don't know if it fits other purposes, but at least I could continue with other stuff. Strangely it works if you change the name of the key of the $_SESSION array and add a by reference assignment, `$_SESSION['a_aux'] = &$a;`. Worked on PHP 5.5 and PHP 5.2.17.

```
<?php

class A
{
    public $var = 0;
}

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['a_array']))
{

    $a = new A();
    $a->var = rand();

    array_push($_SESSION['a_array'], $a);

    $_SESSION['a_aux'] = &$a;

}
else
{

    $a_array = Array();
    $_SESSION['a_array'] = $a_array;

}

var_dump($_SESSION['a_array']);

?>
```